# How to show table from value in dropdown? codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, dropdown

I have a dropdown like this:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    Pilih Manajemen asset yang akan ditampilkan :
    <select name="laporan">
        <option value="">Manajemen Aset</option>
        <option value="panel">Laporan Penel</option>
        <option value="lampu">Laporan Lampu</option>
    </select>
    <input class="command-button primary" type="submit" name="tampilkan" value="Tampilkan">
</form>
```

What I want is:
If I chose value "panel" from the dropdown and I clicked the button (name="tampilkan"), it will show table. And if I choose value "lampu", it will show different table.

I tried with this code :

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['tampilkan'])) {
    if(isset($_POST['laporan'])== 'panel') {
?>
       //will shown table 1


     <?php
    }

    else if(isset($_POST['laporan'])== 'lampu') {
        ?>

        //will shown table 2
    <?php
    }

}
?>
```

But it doesn't work. I really need your help, thanks.

Comment: what is an error you are getting ??

Comment: what is the current status with given code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concept is to check isset only once.

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['tampilkan'])) {
        if($_POST['laporan']== 'panel') {
    ?>
           //will shown table 1


         <?php
        }

        else if($_POST['laporan'] == 'lampu') {
            ?>

            //will shown table 2
        <?php
        }

    }
    ?>
```

OR

```
if(isset($_POST['tampilkan']) && $_POST['laporan']== 'panel') {
           // Show table 1
 }
elseif(isset($_POST['tampilkan']) && $_POST['laporan']== 'lampu') {
           // Show table 2
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have problem with your `if` condition. Try this condition :

```
if(isset($_POST['laporan']) && $_POST['laporan'] == 'panel') {
    echo "TAB1";
}
```